How to assign value to a zero dimensional torch tensor?
z = torch.tensor(1, dtype= torch.int64)
z[:] = 5

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: slice() cannot be applied to a 0-dim tensor.

I'm trying to assign a value to a torch tensor but because it has zero dimensions the slice operator doesn't work. How do I assign a new value then?

This is actually possible with copy_:
z = torch.tensor(1, dtype=torch.int32)
z.copy_(3.)
>>> tensor(3, dtype=torch.int32)

This will also cast it to the dtype of my variable.

You can index with the empty index (i.e. an empty tuple ()) into a 0-d tensor:
import torch

z = torch.tensor(1, dtype=torch.int64)

z[()] = 5
print(z)
# >>> tensor(5)

The Numpy documentation¹ states: An empty (tuple) index is a full scalar index into a zero-dimensional array – which is exactly what you need in this case.
Likewise, you can use an ellipsis ...:
z[...] = 42
print(z)
# >>> tensor(42)

Slicing with the colon : requires at least one dimension being present in the tensor. Neither the empty index () nor ellipsis ... have this requirement.
¹) I did not find a corresponding statement in the PyTorch docs, but apparently PyTorch follows the same paradigm.

You can do an in-place operation e.g. multiplication:
z *= 5

You can also directly assign the value to the underlying data property of the tensor:
z.data = torch.tensor(5)

Note that, autograd (Pytorch's backpropagation engine) would not track any computation made directly on a tensor's data attribute.

overwriting the data works, however I believe it will write it to a different memory location each time

how about something like: a = torch.tensor(60.); a.lerp_(torch.tensor(5.),torch.tensor(1.))

@Anonymous In-place operations should write to the same memory location; check with z.data_ptr() to get an idea. (Python's own id function would also help in this case).

yeah though in-place requires some mathematical operations. I find it hard to believe torch doesn't have an assign functionality for tensors. or maybe it does have some internal unpublished function with said mechanism?
